# How to Make Macbook a Slave Display for Raspberry Pi 3b?

Tags: display, macos

I need to get displays for my microprocessors which I need for different tasks. I can have a USB-microUSB-HDMI connection to the ultrabook. 
I am using Macbook Air 2013-mid and El Capitan 10.11.4.

---

How can you make Macbook a Slave Display for Raspberry Pi 3b.

Comment: Without literally disassembling the computer, you can't do so directly. There might be some software workarounds involving a headless Raspberry Pi and screen sharing software, but I would seriously recommend just getting another display.

Comment: @JMY1000 It is impossible sometimes. I can get old phone and make it a slave if it is possible. Install a new OS etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely not feasible, and likely impossible. Whatever ports are for video and audio on your MacBook Air would be *out*, like to an external display, not in. You could possibly disassemble the MacBook Air and spent an absolutely ridiculous amount of time (and maybe money) to *maybe* get it to work, but really, you just need a separate display.

Comment: Can you recommend any other Ultrabook, and/or laptop for the task? i need to soon update my ultrabook.

Comment: @Masi I wouldn't recommend any non-Apple laptop, after using Windows for years. You should just find a monitor specifically for that Raspberry Pi, as I seriously doubt any Windows laptop will work that way and a new laptop would be more than a monitor anyway.

Comment: I can put any OS to any laptop what I want. I thinking some Linux laptops but have not found any good one. Open-source community does not support any latest laptops, only many years old ones.  I think missing such a feature in Macbook air motivates me to shift.

Comment: @Masi Well, you asked for my recommendation and I gave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible...

Comment: Please add more details about *why* it's not possible and if there are any other plausible workarounds.